UK children's show from mid-late 90s that had a building showing different videos
I just remembered an old children's TV show from when I was little and I'm curious if anyone knows what it was. I was born at the end of 1992 so I'm guessing somewhere between 1995-2000 on the BBC, I remember a tv show called Oakey Doke from around then, which was apparently 1996.
It was sort of a collection of stories, where it'd show a colourful rounded building filled with rooms, each with a different video relating to the different characters. It then focuses on one of the videos and you'd see the story for it. I can't tell you if it had multiple or just one per episode though.
The one that I remember particularly liking was some guy who had a black room and some sort of a magic pen. He was able to draw things on the wall then pick them up and use them.
There was also some nerdy girl I think as one of the main recurring characters, but I think I remember that as she appeared all the time but I didn't like her haha.
Horrible picture but I remember it looking something like this (walls are intentionally not square) -


+1 for the nice drawing

Was it Zzzap? 
It was on CITV and I didn't like the girl either! 
https://g.co/kgs/jZTkO0

Yes, that was it haha, thanks :P
